# Cytoscape error during network analysis - java.lang.exception?

Tags: java, cytoscape

I'm trying to use Cytoscape and the ANIMO app for the first time but I'm having trouble and getting stuck. Any help would be much appreciated!!

I'm using simple test networks (2-3 nodes) but I get a recurrent error when I try to analyse the networks. If I run Cytoscape from shell I get the following:

```
karaf@Cytoscape 3.7.2()> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.


animo.core.analyser.AnalysisException: Error during analysis: <pre>java.lang.Exception: [/Users/Carla/CytoscapeConfiguration/3/karaf_data/tmp/ANIMO7219678590825060215.xml] Verify result: 134
 empty result
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Wed, 04 Mar 2020 16:48:28 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4
Content-Length: 226
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>

 (current directory: /Applications/Cytoscape_v3.7.2/framework/.)

    at animo.core.analyser.uppaal.UppaalModelAnalyserSMC.analyze(UppaalModelAnalyserSMC.java:666)
    at animo.cytoscape.RunAction$RunTask.performNormalAnalysis(RunAction.java:141)
    at animo.cytoscape.RunAction$RunTask.run(RunAction.java:312)
    at org.cytoscape.work.internal.task.JDialogTaskManager$TaskRunnable.innerRun(JDialogTaskManager.java:321)
    at org.cytoscape.work.internal.task.JDialogTaskManager$TaskRunnable.run(JDialogTaskManager.java:352)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
</pre>
    at animo.core.analyser.uppaal.UppaalModelAnalyserSMC.analyze(UppaalModelAnalyserSMC.java:683)
    at animo.cytoscape.RunAction$RunTask.performNormalAnalysis(RunAction.java:141)
    at animo.cytoscape.RunAction$RunTask.run(RunAction.java:312)
    at org.cytoscape.work.internal.task.JDialogTaskManager$TaskRunnable.innerRun(JDialogTaskManager.java:321)
    at org.cytoscape.work.internal.task.JDialogTaskManager$TaskRunnable.run(JDialogTaskManager.java:352)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: [/Users/Carla/CytoscapeConfiguration/3/karaf_data/tmp/ANIMO7219678590825060215.xml] Verify result: 134
 empty result
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Wed, 04 Mar 2020 16:48:28 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4
Content-Length: 226
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>

 (current directory: /Applications/Cytoscape_v3.7.2/framework/.)

    at animo.core.analyser.uppaal.UppaalModelAnalyserSMC.analyze(UppaalModelAnalyserSMC.java:666)
    ... 9 more
```

I also run the troubleshooting script and got this...

```
Target Cytoscape version: 3.7.2
Your shell is bash
Compatible OS version found: 10.14
 - Pass: OS Version = 10.14.6
 - Pass: Following Oracle JDK found:

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk
 - Pass: Current Java Version = 1.8.0_151
 - Pass: JAVA_HOME found: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home
Checking connection to Cytoscape App Store...
5 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
Looks connection to App Store is unstable.
Please check firewall setting from System Preference.
traceroute result:
traceroute to apps.cytoscape.org (52.34.133.210), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  172.27.109.254 (172.27.109.254)  1.542 ms  1.095 ms  1.026 ms
 2  …
```

I checked the firewall options on my Mac and Cytoscape is set to "Allow incoming connections". I'm very much a biology user, so I have no clue how to go forward...

Thanks a lot for your help!!

CM

Comment: 4xx errors mean that the network connection works and the server has rejected your request: make sure you are running the latest version of the ANIMO2 plugin. traceroute failure: try running it on the network that does not require a proxy, otherwise make sure it's configured. You should not need to allow incoming connections unless you want to run a server on your machine and let others access it. Most likely, you should file a bug with the ANIMO2 developers or to use a tool like Fiddler to find a bug and help ANIMO2 to fix it, most likely due to a change in Cytoscape API.

Comment: If you do not have patience for all of this, you can try running Cytoscape 3.4 because it's the last version ANIMO was [tested for](http://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/animo) (see under Release History).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. You are right about not needing the connection, but it tries to connect even if I change the settings. I checked and I have the latest version of ANIMO too. I also tried running Cytoscape 3.4 but I get exactly the same error... I'll try to contact the developers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks berezovskyi for the suggestions. FYI in case anyone struggles too, the authors (Stefano Schivo) suggested a solution that worked. The solution was to use old versions of both ANIMO, UPPAAL and Cytoscape. Below are the versions that worked together.

Cytoscape 3.4.0

Java 1.8.0_151

ANIMO 3.4.0

UPPAAL 4.1.19

Thanks, CM